# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidSessionTimeoutException's no record information is available

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices

I had created a Kafka consumer using Azure Event Hub and Spring Boot, but when I start the application and then begin to try to consume the messages that I have in my broker I receive the error bellow

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidSessionTimeoutException's; no record information is available
     at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:151) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:103) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1247) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1004) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidSessionTimeoutException: The session timeout is not within the range allowed by the broker (as configured by group.min.session.timeout.ms and group.max.session.timeout.ms).

2020-07-22 17:09:28.017  INFO 2582630 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=ed3c3738-5b4d-4a83-8c19-76f0a11316bb-0, groupId=com.hi.servicemessagestatusprocessor.ServiceMessageStatusProcessorApplication] (Re-)joining group
2020-07-22 17:09:28.035 ERROR 2582630 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=ed3c3738-5b4d-4a83-8c19-76f0a11316bb-0, groupId=com.hi.servicemessagestatusprocessor.ServiceMessageStatusProcessorApplication] Attempt to join group failed due to fatal error: The session timeout is not within the range allowed by the broker (as configured by group.min.session.timeout.ms and group.max.session.timeout.ms).
2020-07-22 17:09:28.035  INFO 2582630 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=ed3c3738-5b4d-4a83-8c19-76f0a11316bb-0, groupId=com.hi.servicemessagestatusprocessor.ServiceMessageStatusProcessorApplication] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidSessionTimeoutException: The session timeout is not within the range allowed by the broker (as configured by group.min.session.timeout.ms and group.max.session.timeout.ms).
2020-07-22 17:09:28.036 ERROR 2582630 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Consumer exception
```

I can't figure out how to resolve this error, bellow have my configuration to Kafka consumer

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    public ConsumerFactory<String, HilabMessage> consumerFactory(String groupId) throws IOException {
        InputStream kafkaProperties = getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("kafka.properties");

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(kafkaProperties);

        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        for (final String name: properties.stringPropertyNames())
            configs.put(name, properties.getProperty(name));

        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1");
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        configs.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class.getName());

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
            configs, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(HilabMessage.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, HilabMessage> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() throws IOException {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, HilabMessage> factory = new 
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(ServiceMessageStatusProcessorApplication.class.getName()));
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Note that my producer has a similar configuration and it publishes the messages to the broker

Comment: I'm running an Azure Event Hub with Kafka enable, It's on the cloud

Comment: Isn't the `MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG` too low? Can you try putting 5000 (5 second)?

Comment: Nope, the problem continues.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was the MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, I configured to be 30000, and that's worked, but I think that a higher number to MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG

Comment: Nice to know. Even I though I suspected it, I didn't expect it has to be that high. Glad you sorted it out. Anyway heart beat is separate from poll now in kafka so it is not that bad.